# In Express.js, how do I set a wildcard route to not match for asset files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I'm building my first real Express.js app, and stuck on the routing.

I am enabling static hosting:

```
app.use("/", express.static("public"));
```

And then I have a wildcard route:

```
router.get("/:page", function(req, res) {
    // do stuff
});
```

This route is matching for urls like "`/about`" and "`/contact`" - which I want. But it appears that it's also trying to match for "`/style.css`" and other static asset files - which is unnecessary.

How do I make this wildcard not match for asset files?

Comment: What order are these defined in your express initialization?  The easy way to differentiate is to put `/lib` or `/static` or something like that on the front of the path of all static assets (and in the `app.use()` for your static files) so there is no confusion between static assets and dynamic ones.

Comment: I am doing these steps in the order listed above. I added a "/static/" prefix to the app.use and it did not solve the problem, I still see style.css and favicon.ico requests getting processed by the route.get.  I'm thinking maybe I need a regex expression that says router.get should ignore the URL if it contains a period?

Comment: If you do this `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));` and then change all your static file paths in your HTML files to be like `/static/styles.css`, you should be OK.

Comment: Per [this route tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/?_ga=1.14570423.1498155636.1421037555), `/static/styles.css` will not match `/:page` so the above should work.

Comment: Thanks! That solution won't work out for my needs (I need the asset folders to live at root level), but I appreciate the brainstorming!

Comment: Why do asset files have to live at root path?  You're trying to mix static routes with dynamic routes which just makes things a lot more complicated.  Yes, there's probably a way to do it, but why make things complicated?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I found, is to search for a "." inside the query and then set a flag if it's found:

```
router.get("/:page", function(req, res) {
    if (req.render_view) res.render("index");
});

router.param("page", function(req, res, next, page) {

    // if request is not an asset file      
    if (page.indexOf(".") == -1) {

        // do stuff

        // set a flag
        req.render_view = true;

    }

    next(); 

});
```

But I would like to find a cleaner solution, possibly using a regular expression in the router.get?

Answer (score -1):

if I understand what you want to do ,you should just do something like :

app.js

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
 app.use('/:page',function(){}..)
```

this configuration works when ur public and static folder is relative to app.js, when browser request for static file , first server will look at public folder , if file is no there will continue to static folder and finally to /:page